# ODE of continuous multivariate function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

This question is pretty similar to the one discussed here: [ODE of multivariate function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4257966/ode-of-multivariate-function). The problem that we have is:
$$
\frac{df(x, t)}{dt} = p(x) + c\int_{y}g(x, y)f(y,t) \, dy + cf(x,t)
.
$$
But this time, both $x$ and $t$ are continuous.

The context of the problem and the background of me, as the author of both questions are the same, except that now I know how we can approach the previously mentioned problem.

My questions are:

- Is this any specific general form (like Linear Separable ODEs) to which this problem belongs?
- Is this problem solvable? If so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Note:
$$e^{ct}\frac{\partial e^{-ct}f(x,t)}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}-cf$$
Then your equation becomes:
$$\frac{\partial e^{-ct}f(x,t)}{\partial t}=\int_yg(x,y)e^{-ct}f(y,t)dy + p(x)$$

Let $w(x,t) = e^{-ct}f(x,t)$, then
$$\frac{\partial w(x,t)}{\partial t}=\int_yg(x,y)w(y,t)dy + p(x)$$

It is possible to rewrite your equation as a separable equation, $w_t = G(w)$, so that $\int {1\over G(w)}dw = t-t_0$. $G$ can be viewed as a convolution of a kernel $g$ onto a moving image $w$ that is added onto a static image $p$. But without an explicit form of $G$, there is no general solution.

Your best approach is numerical, discretizing $w_t$ as $\frac{w(t+\Delta t)-w(t)}{\Delta t}$.